# How To Disable This JS Function In Responsive Designs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design

I am using a script in my blog http://www.helpitx.com which makes a widget floating sticky. Currently I am using this script for navigation menu but it destroys layout of responsive design specially for mobile devices which have screen height less than 768px because whole menu isn't displayed there.
Here is the script that I am using.

```
<script>
/*<![CDATA[*/
// Sticky Plugin
// =============
// Author: Syed Faizan Ali
(function($) {
    var defaults = {
            topSpacing: 0,
            bottomSpacing: 0,
            className: 'is-sticky',
            center: false
        },
        $window = $(window),
        $document = $(document),
        sticked = [],
        windowHeight = $window.height(),
        scroller = function() {
            var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop(),
                documentHeight = $document.height(),
                dwh = documentHeight - windowHeight,
                extra = (scrollTop > dwh) ? dwh - scrollTop : 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < sticked.length; i++) {
                var s = sticked[i],
                    elementTop = s.stickyWrapper.offset().top,
                    etse = elementTop - s.topSpacing - extra;
                if (scrollTop <= etse) {
                    if (s.currentTop !== null) {
                        s.stickyElement.css('position', '').css('top', '').removeClass(s.className);
                        s.currentTop = null;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    var newTop = documentHeight - s.elementHeight - s.topSpacing - s.bottomSpacing - scrollTop - extra;
                    if (newTop < 0) {
                        newTop = newTop + s.topSpacing;
                    } else {
                        newTop = s.topSpacing;
                    }
                    if (s.currentTop != newTop) {
                        s.stickyElement.css('position', 'fixed').css('top', newTop).addClass(s.className);
                        s.currentTop = newTop;
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        resizer = function() {
            windowHeight = $window.height();
        };
    // should be more efficient than using $window.scroll(scroller) and $window.resize(resizer):
    if (window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', scroller, false);
        window.addEventListener('resize', resizer, false);
    } else if (window.attachEvent) {
        window.attachEvent('onscroll', scroller);
        window.attachEvent('onresize', resizer);
    }
    $.fn.sticky = function(options) {
        var o = $.extend(defaults, options);
        return this.each(function() {
            var stickyElement = $(this);
            if (o.center)
                var centerElement = "margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;";
            stickyId = stickyElement.attr('id');
            stickyElement
                .wrapAll('<div id="' + stickyId + 'StickyWrapper" style="' + centerElement + '"></div>')
                .css('width', stickyElement.width());
            var elementHeight = stickyElement.outerHeight(),
                stickyWrapper = stickyElement.parent();
            stickyWrapper
                .css('width', stickyElement.outerWidth())
                .css('height', elementHeight)
                .css('clear', stickyElement.css('clear'));
            sticked.push({
                topSpacing: o.topSpacing,
                bottomSpacing: o.bottomSpacing,
                stickyElement: stickyElement,
                currentTop: null,
                stickyWrapper: stickyWrapper,
                elementHeight: elementHeight,
                className: o.className
            });
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
/*]]>*/
</script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $(&quot;#mblfloater&quot;).sticky({topSpacing:0});
   });
</script>
```

I have enclosed my navigation menu in  tag. The script is working fine but I want to disable it in mobile devices which have screen width less than 768. How could it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
   $(document).ready(function(){
    if ($(window).width() >= 768) {
        $("#mblfloater").sticky({topSpacing:0});
    }
   });
</script>
```

Only run the script if the window's width is greater than or equal to (i.e. not less than) 768.

Comment: Don't forget to [mark it as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) to let others know that your problem is solved. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hide the menu using a [CSS media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

For example:

```
<style>
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  #mblfloater {
    display: none;
  }
}
</style>
```

Comment: I tried this first but it hides the whole navigation menu instead of blocking sticky function only.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using jQuery:

```
if($(window).outerWidth() < 768){
   //disable your code here
}
```

Comment: Actually I am new to javascript and don't know what is working behind this script. Anyways, if I use it then what shall I do to disable the code?